# I'm getting "command not found" error after running these commands in GitLab. I used these commands 2 days ago and they worked fine

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecs

I was using these commands for my deploy-job the other day and it worked fine. This is a new pipeline for a new project and now these commands aren't working. I'm getting errors in my pipeline after every command saying "command not found". Here's my gitlab-ci file for reference

```
variables:
  DOCKER_REGISTRY: 775362094965.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-west-2
  APP_NAME: flask-app
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build-job:
  stage: build
  image: 
    name: amazon/aws-cli
    entrypoint: [""]
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - amazon-linux-extras install docker
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:latest . 
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:latest

deploy-job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo `aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition  $CI_AWS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION --region us-west-2` > input.json
    - echo $(cat input.json | jq '.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[].image="'$REPOSITORY_URI':'$IMAGE_TAG'"') >  input.json
    - echo $(cat input.json | jq '.taskDefinition') > input.json
    - echo $(cat input.json | jq  'del(.taskDefinitionArn)' | jq 'del(.revision)' | jq 'del(.status)' | jq 'del(.requiresAttributes)' | jq 'del(.compatibilities)' | jq 'del(.registeredAt)' | jq 'del(.registeredBy)') > input.json
    - aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://input.json --region us-west-2 
    - revision=$(aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition $CI_AWS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION --region us-west-2 | egrep "revision" | tr "/" " " | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/"$//' | cut -d "," -f 1)
    - aws ecs update-service --cluster $CI_AWS_ECS_CLUSTER --service $CI_AWS_ECS_SERVICE  --task-definition $CI_AWS_ECS_TASK_DEFINITION:$revision --region us-west-2
```

My build-job works fine, I'm just getting "command not found" with my deploy-job.

Comment: There are many questions to be asked here. First, Can you please tell us what GitLab runner executer you are using for this? is it docker or SSH?
Also, If you can share the error logs so we can identify what is the "not founded command".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an image outside of the build job or in the deploy job. Right now, you're only specifying an image inside your build-job.